# redirecting output of command run under xargs separately per-file

Tags: sqlite, csv, xargs

I'm trying to dump a load of sqlite tables to .csv format from the cmd line using xargs, i.e.

```
find . -name "*.db" -print0 \
  | xargs -0 -I {} sqlite3 -header -csv {} "select * from pulse_data;" > {}.csv
```

For some reason its writing to `{}.csv` rather than each `.db` file in turn.

Is there a problem with using the `{}` notation more than once?

If I run it without the redirect it seems to work as expected, i.e.

```
find . -name "*.db" -print0 \
  | xargs -0 -I {} sqlite3 -header -csv {} "select * from pulse_data;"
```

just prints all the `.db` tables to stdout as expected in .csv format

How can i get it to redirect to a suitably named file, i.e. `<file-name>.db.csv`?

Comment: As an addendum that may explain a little more/better _why_ the original behavior was taking place, by the way -- redirections are performed by the shell *before* the command being launched is executed; so by the time `xargs` is invoked, the redirection of stdout to a file named `{}` has already happened. (I've edited my answer to make that explicit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` doesn't start a shell, so you can't do shell redirections from it (unless your command is explicitly `xargs sh -c ...`). In the code given in the question, `>{}` is executed by the parent shell before `xargs` is even started -- it isn't aware of the redirection attempt at all.

Since you aren't doing anything here that significantly benefits from xargs (like parallelism), the cost of launching shells under it isn't justified. Just read the list from your outer shell.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  sqlite3 -header -csv "$filename" "select * from pulse_data;" >"$filename.csv"
done < <(find . -name '*.db' -print0)  # See footnote 1
```

If you *really* want to use xargs for some reason:

```
find . -name '*.db' -print0 \
  | xargs -0 sh -c '
      for filename; do
        sqlite3 -header -csv "$filename" "select * from pulse_data;" >"$filename.csv"
      done' _ {} +
```

---

Footnote 1:  Note that `<()` is a feature not present in POSIX sh -- but ksh, zsh and bash will all have it; if you need compatibility with `/bin/sh`, you can pipe from `find` to the `while` loop instead, but be aware that [this comes with some caveats](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: not especially - just have a pile of .db files i need to convert to .csv, no desire to do it manually via a GUI so need a suitable cmd line alternative to do the work - whatever method is simplest is the one i am looking for